# Placeholder not showing on dropdown, can anybody tell me why?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui

I am trying to render a Dropdown with a placeholder but the placeholder doesnt render. I'm not sure why. My Dropdown is as follows.

```
<Dropdown
  loading={loading}
  error={!!error}
  inline
  value={this.props.entityId || null}
  onChange={(e, { value }) => {
    client.writeData({data: {teamBudget: value, __typename: 'TeamBudget'}})
  }}
  options={options}
  placeholder={options ? 'Select Draft' : 'Error!'}
/>
```

when I comment out value the placeholder displays as expected. Can value not be defined along with placeholder?

Comment: What is `Dropdown` a third party component or yours?

Comment: It is a component of semantic-ui https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/

Comment: Seems working as expected in normal Dropdown component, may be issue is something else in your case. Here's the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v95js

Comment: have you tried removing props from the dropdown one by one to see if its a specific usage? also try just rendering the dropdown with hardcoded values to see if the placeholder works

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the component you are using,
but the common convention is,

value={the value you are expecting to display **inside** the dropdown field}

which should be in a label value pair

eg: [{ value: '1', label: 'one' }]

i can only suspect your **this.props.entityId** isn't in this format.
also, that could be the reason it sabotages the placeholder.

FYI: usually, if you don't mention value={} in props, it handles it by default,
 which could be the reason it works properly when ommits...